# Network ping replies: latency alternates low and high

Tags: linux, networking, latency

I'm experiencing some troubles with one machine in my network. When I ping it the ping replies rotates like this :

```
64 bytes from 10.0.100.10: icmp_seq=156 ttl=62 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.10: icmp_seq=157 ttl=62 time=1099 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.10: icmp_seq=158 ttl=62 time=93.0 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.10: icmp_seq=159 ttl=62 time=1091 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.10: icmp_seq=160 ttl=62 time=84.3 ms
```

What could cause that kind of problem? The machine I'm pinging is ubuntu 12.04 server.
I can't access it trough ssh but it's up and running.

Comment: Honestly, only going by ping won't get you very far, you'll have to look into your network more thoroughly. A good tool for your initial testing would be http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's failing disk causing the problem in general.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Glad you resolved this. Please be sure to [mark your answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I would *never* have thought it was disk related. The machine that was responding oddly has an ssd w/ lvm partitions. I just ran `sudo fstrim -av` it TRIMed a bunch, rebooted (for other reasons) and so far ping latency is excellent. From results like you reported to consistent 5-10ms.